# How to use tags in string resource?

Tags: wpf, string, xaml, tags, resources

In wpf application I bind text from resource file to TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{DynamicResource localDriverUpdatesNote}" Style="{DynamicResource BodyText}" />
```

In resource file I have the following string:

```
<sys:String x:Key="localDriverUpdatesNote">To check for updates to your system, click Check.</sys:String>
```

But I need word **Check** to be bold.

If I use:

```
<sys:String x:Key="localDriverUpdatesNote">To check for updates to your system, click <Bold>Check</Bold>.</sys:String>
```

I got:

> error MC3089: The object 'String' already has a child and cannot add
>   ''. 'String' can accept only one child.

So, I can't use tags inside string.

I can split string to two and create two TextBlocks and apply different style to second, but I don't think it's good solution.

Maybe create string converter and use some symbols to mark text as bold?

Is there other way to make one word bold?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  Perhaps you can try with a custom value converter.

Comment: See [TextBlock.Inlines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Clemens, can you give example how to use it?

Comment: @Clemens, but how I add tags in resource string?

Comment: You can't. But you can assign a string with tags to the Inlines collection of a TextBlock. Or you may use markdown syntax, as done (only for hyperlinks) here: https://github.com/ClemensFischer/XAML-Map-Control/blob/master/MapControl/Shared/HyperlinkText.cs

Comment: @Clemens, but how to add these strings to inline collection? And how to use resources to keep these strings?